# Error in UseMethod("cld") : no applicable method for 'cld' applied to an object of class "data.frame"

Tags: r

I'm running this mixed model:

```
 dflm1 <- lmer(formula=df[,16] ~  trt + (1|id), data=df)
emm <- emmeans(dflm1,'trt')
library(multcomp)
cld(emm) 
Error in UseMethod("cld") : 
  no applicable method for 'cld' applied to an object of class "data.frame"
```

Unfortunately I cant upload the data. I have looked at other questions about this but it doesn't get right. I have both changed trt and id to be numeric and factors, but the same error occur. Does anyone have a clue why I get this error? Earlier it worked so I must have changed something, but I don't know what!!?

Comment: You're trying to pass a data frame to the `cld` function, but that doesn't make any sense - this function has to be supplied with a `ghlt` model. You need to make one first. You do this by passing `dflm1` to the `ghlt` function from multcomp.

Comment: @Allan Cameron, thanks! Could you elaborate on how I do this?

Comment: The help page of `cld` has many examples (scroll down towards the bottom of the page). __Maybe try__: `glht1 <- glht(dflm1, linfct = mcp(trt = "Tukey")); cld(glht1)`

Comment: Re-Run the code, I guess, because `emmeans()` produces an `emmGrid` object, not a `data.frame`, and there *is* a method for `emmGrid`. You do not have to convert it to `glht`.

Comment: Has something changed in the recent version of the `multcomp` package? I just updated R, RStudio and my packages and  suddenly old code isn't working. Even the example from this help page is putting out an error https://rdrr.io/cran/emmeans/man/CLD.emmGrid.html

Answer (score 0):

I tried using CLD(emm) instead of cld(emm) and it worked!  Here is my source:
https://rdrr.io/cran/emmeans/man/CLD.emmGrid.html

Hope this works!